# What does it mean for a clock to be "running late" or "running early"?

Tags: phrase-meaning, difference, phrase-choice

My understanding is that if a clock is running "2 minutes fast" or "2 minutes ahead", that means it displays 09:02 when the true time is 09:00, whereas if a clock is "2 minutes slow" or "2 minutes behind", then it displays 08:58 when the true time is 09:00.

But what if the clock is running "2 minutes late" or "2 minutes early"? If the true time is 09:00, which one of these phrases means that it displays 08:58 and which means it displays 09:02? I can construct arguments for both interpretations.

If a clock is running "2 minutes late" then one natural interpretation is that I will be 2 minutes late to things if I use it as my timepiece. So then it would display 08:58. (Also, "late" seems like a more natural synonym for "slow" and "behind".)

On the other hand, 09:02 is two minutes later than 09:00, so another seemingly natural interpretation is that a clock that is "2 minutes late" would display 09:02 instead of 09:00.

Comment: Can you say where you found that phrase? People run late but not clocks in my experience.

Comment: It was a note written on a the bottom of a form documenting the times of some events. Apparently the clock of the person completing the form was out of sync. But I am not sure in which direction to adjust the times on the form in order to account for the note. I assumed it was an acceptable phrase that I did not understand. If it is not an acceptable phrase then I will have to write back to the person who completed the form to understand what they meant. I will probably do this anyway, but I wanted to determine if the phrase had a well-understood meaning first.

Comment: People in the UK may say 'I was running late', e.g. to explain why they didn't buy a railway ticket before they boarded a train. It does not impress the magistrates and they still get the fine.

Comment: It is probably an error.  As you say it is on a note, not something that is carefully written.  Best guess is the the person meant "running slow".  However, since this is not idiomatic and is a mistaken expression, there is no real way to be sure.  On that basis, I will vote to close.  Good question (+1), unfortunately unanswerable.